# playing flash videos in ios browsers

Tags: ios, flash, browser

I have a scenario where I have to play videos using `flash player` in iOS device's browser. Offically Apple does not support flash, so is there any way of playing flash videos in iOS devices?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a flash to html5 converter like Google swiffy:
https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/

Answer (score 0):

[**Swiffy**](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/releasenotes.html) has been regularly upgraded since 2011 and does a very good job, although expect much bigger file sizes.

Also, looped event sounds in your FLA files (if any) will play only once (i.e. they don't loop). What is more, event sounds play in Swiffy in PC browsers, but currently do not play on iOS devices. Stream sound isn't supported in Swiffy yet, on any device.